# Azure Stream analytics can not retrieve ML endpoint swagger

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-stream-analytics

I successfully deployed a model on Azure machine learning studio following the official [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?tabs=python#optional-define-model-web-service-schema)
The endpoint and the deployment are successfull, I can invoke it without any problem. I also added the schema as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script).

The swagger.json uri is available, i can get it.
When I try to add a function from azure stream analytics to this endpoint I always get this error on the Function signature:

> Unexpected error occurred while retrieving swagger endpoint definition. Please check if the url provided is valid and that the web service is responsive.

As I said, the url is valid and the web service is responsive. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Azure Machine Learning functions to your Stream Analytics job directly from the Azure portal or Visual Studio Code.

Can you check the Swagger uri presence in the endpoint from the portal ml.azure.com and test is input and output working or not?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/machine-learning-udf